# How do I stack these containers to stack horizontally?

Tags: html, css

Code at
https://codepen.io/shayaansiddiqui/pen/YzGzeOj

How do I stack these boxes horizontally?

```
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="#" alt="Norway" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="text-block">
            <h4>Video 1</h4>
            <p>By YouTube Star</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="#" alt="Norway" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="text-block">
            <h4>Video 2</h4>
            <p>By Another YouTube Star</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="#" alt="Norway" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="text-block">
            <h4>Video 3</h4>
            <p>By Jason Bourne</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean `container` should be in horizontal?

Comment: If yes, use `flex` on parent div, that's enough to keep `container` in horizontal

Comment: if you see codepen, you'll see the container is stacked vertical. I want to get it stacked horizontally

Comment: Are you creating a slideshow - like thing? Because if we stack the content horizontally then it will overflow because you have set the width of individual container 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example with `flex`. I have removed the nav and heading and added placeholder images.

```css
img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 250px;
}

.text-block {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color:#ef21219f;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 150px;
}

#flex{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div class="container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Norway" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="text-block">
        <h4>Video 1</h4>
        <p>By YouTube Star</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Norway" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="text-block">
        <h4>Video 2</h4>
        <p>By Another YouTube Star</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Norway" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="text-block">
        <h4>Video 3</h4>
        <p>By Jason Bourne</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note** - View the snippet in full-screen mode as the content may mess up in small size because of positioning.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS,

```
.container{
display : inline-block;
}
```

Will do the work,

More styling,

```
Width : 30%;
margin: 0px 1%;
verical-align: top;
```